# Can't set login activity before mainactivity

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

In my android app, i used firebase to sign in with google, but can't set the login activity before main. 
Here's the stack trace:

```
02-12 23:57:02.524 8692-8692/bf_d.binary_femaledefense E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: bf_d.binary_femaledefense, PID: 8692
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bf_d.binary_femaledefense/bf_d.binary_femaledefense.login}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process bf_d.binary_femaledefense. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process bf_d.binary_femaledefense. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source:54)
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                         at bf_d.binary_femaledefense.login.onCreate(login.java:53)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

l already called the FirebaseAuth.initializeApp(this) in the onCreate method. But still showing initializing error in FirebaseApp.

Here's the library i used:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

And here is my AndroidManifest:

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactSetup"
        android:parentActivityName=".ContextSetup" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EditContacts"
        android:parentActivityName=".EditContacts" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HowTo"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutDevs"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RecordHistory"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomText"
        android:parentActivityName=".ContextSetup" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContextSetup"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
</application>
```

Any Suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: There are 3 videos in one of my tutorials that will help you. I explained step by step how it can be done. Take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&index=5&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee).

Comment: @PeterHaddad I'm trying to help the OP to understand better with a concrete example. Having the LoginActivity before MainActivy is apart of that tutorial. Btw, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Stop leaving comments rather than solving the problem :)

Comment: @Asif-UlIslamAkash please see the answer below here,the duplicate question, and the video surely it will work with you after all of that

Answer (score 0):

Extend Application class and call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` in `onCreate()` method of that class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    }
}
```

And add `android:name` attribute to your manifest

```
<application 
    android:name=". MyApplication"
...
>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, "Override Application Class" ?

Comment: Still doesn't help